# Getting wrong y_pred values from model.predict

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, transfer-learning, resnet

First of all I am very new to deep learning. Here I want to create a confusion matrix. For this reason, I need y_pred and y_true. I calculated y_true and y_pred the following way:

```
y_true = test_gen.classes

y_pred = (model.predict(test_gen)>0.5).astype("int32")
```

My confusion matrix code is:

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix
print('Confusion Matrix')
print(confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred ))
mat = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)
```

I set `metrics=['accuracy','TruePositives', 'TrueNegatives', 'FalsePositives', 'FalseNegatives']` in my model.compile

```
best_model = model
best_model.load_weights('./classify_model.h5')
best_model.evaluate(test_gen)
```

The value that I get for TruePositives,TrueNegatives, FalsePositives,FalseNegatives from `best_model.evaluate(test_gen)` don't match with my confusion matrix value.

**My Train dataset:**

[image]

**My test dataset:**

[image]

```
target_size=(224,224)
batch_size=64

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    preprocessing_function=tf.keras.applications.resnet_v2.preprocess_input,
    horizontal_flip=True, zoom_range=0.1
)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    preprocessing_function=tf.keras.applications.resnet_v2.preprocess_input
)

train_gen = train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
    train_df,
    directory=train_path,
    x_col='file_paths',
    y_col='labels',
    target_size=target_size,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    color_mode='rgb',
    class_mode='binary'
)


valid_gen = test_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
    valid_df,
    directory=train_path,
    x_col='file_paths',
    y_col='labels', 
    target_size=target_size,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    color_mode='rgb',
    class_mode='binary'
)

test_gen = test_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
    test_df,
    directory=test_path,
    x_col='file_paths',
    y_col='labels',
    target_size=target_size,
    batch_size=batch_size, 
    color_mode='rgb',
    class_mode='binary'
)

base_model = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50V2(include_top=False, input_shape=(224,224,3))


model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    base_model, 
    tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(), 
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(), 
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2), 
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])

lr=0.001
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=lr), metrics=['accuracy', 'TruePositives', 'TrueNegatives', 'FalsePositives', 'FalseNegatives'])
```

I am having trouble calculating `y_true` and `y_pred` correctly. Please help me to construct confusion matrix for this code.

Comment: On dummy data, it gives the same metric values using `evaluate` and `predict` methods. Are you sure that you are using the same model weights?

Comment: Yes, I am sure I used the same model for evaluating and predicting.

Comment: We already have the dataframe which has the `y_true` values. With the help of the neural network classifier which you have built, you can store `y_pred` in a separate column. It will be easier to visualize the actual and predicted values. After that , feed in the 2 columns in the tensorflow confusion matrix function [tf.math.confusion_matrix](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/confusion_matrix)